# Swi Prolog Read Write with Files

Tags: file, encryption, prolog, swi-prolog

So I've been trying to make this encryption predicate and I got it to work for input from the keyboared and standard output but I'm failing to make it work for files,so I need help fixing it.
I need to take the text in MessageFile apply the encryption and write it to  OutFile.

```
encrypt(MessageFile,Key,OutFile):- read(X),q(X,Key,R),!,string_to_list(S,R),
write(S).
```

As I said it works for standard Input\Output:

```
9 ?- encrypt(X,a,Y). 
|   abcdef.             
 bcdefg          
 true.
```

if relevant , My .pl file as well as in.txt and out.txt are in D:\Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a file with:

```
open(MessageFile, read, Read),
```

You can then use `read/2` to read a Prolog term from the file stream:

```
read(Read, Term),
```

PS: Notice that `string_to_list/2` is deprecated and `string_codes/2` is its up-to-date equivalent.